# Would like to have a WMS with colored polygon features but not a legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, symbology, legend, getlegendgraphic

This is in ArcMap 10.3.

- I am creating a WMS with a service definition file (I would like to keep the style how my WMS displays the data) - No problem.
- I have a feature dataset of polygons which I want to plot color coded to differentiate between the features. Symbology -> Categories -> Unique values for that purpose. - No problem.
- However, the resulting legend has a more than a thousand entries in it because I have a lot of polygons. When WMS is used by another user it is the ugliest thing ever if they are also plotting the legend! - Problem!

Is there a way to keep the style (unique colors for each polygon), but prevent the access to the legend? Or is there an alternative way to represent the data to start with?

- Also: I tried disabling the GetLegendGraphic while creating the service definition file. Would that work? I am not the owner of the server so I cannot tweak it at that level. Not sure if all capabilities are turned on no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to this was modifying the underlying dataset:

- Create a new field (such as COLORID) and cycle values from 0 to 9 as values (can be done by calculating filed value as remainder of division of row number by 10, for example)
- Define a categorized symbology with 10 categories based on the COLORID